# onLoadFinished is never called

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cursorloader

It seems that there is a bug in the Support library v4, I want to access the MediaStore Audio using CursorLoader and LoaderManager and I have followed the protocol to the T, and no matter what I do, OnLoaderFinished is not called.

Here are some code snippets, I created something I called MediaStoreInterface,

the relevant parts of MediaStoreInterface are as follows:

```
public class MediaStoreInterface extends Observable
{
protected Cursor cursor;
protected static final int LOADER_ID1 = 1;
protected static final int LOADER_ID2 = 2;
protected static int lastLoaderId = 0; 
protected static String function = "SONGS"; 
protected static PaudioActivity act;
protected static Sound selectedSound = null;
protected static final String[] projections = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
protected static final String[] projectionsPlaylist = {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME};
protected static final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
protected static final Uri uriPlaylists = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
protected static ArrayList<String> ret;
protected static boolean done = false;
//Singleton 

protected static MediaStoreInterface ref = null;


public static MediaStoreInterface getMusicLibrary(Activity act_)
{
    if (ref == null)
        ref = new MediaStoreInterface(act_);

    return ref;     
}

protected MediaStoreInterface(Activity act_)
{
    act = (PaudioActivity) act_;        
}
public static MediaStoreInterface getMSI() 
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
        return MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo.getMusicLibrary(act);
    else
        return MediaStoreInterfaceHoneyComb.getMusicLibrary(act);
}



protected void loadArray(Cursor data) 
{
    int num = data.getColumnCount();
    if (data == null || !data.moveToFirst())
        return;
    while(!data.isLast())
    {
        String s  = data.getString(0);
        int col = 1;
        while(col < num)
            s += "|" + data.getString(col++);
        ret.add(s);
        data.moveToNext();          
    }

    if (function == "SONGS")
        numSongs = ret.size();
    if (function == "PLAYLISTS")
        numPlaylists = ret.size();
    cursor = data;  
}
public static void setDone() 
{
   done = true;     
}



}
```

It's a Singleton, that is supposed to return the right MediaStoreInterface for each API, 
  I extend Frodo from this, as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener;






    public class MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo extends MediaStoreInterface implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor>
    {

        public static MediaStoreInterface getMusicLibrary(Activity act_)
        {
            if (ref == null)
                ref = new MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo(act_);

            return ref;     
        }

        public void setPaudioActivity(PaudioActivity act_)
        {
            act = act_;
        }

        protected MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo(Activity act_) 
        {
            super(act_);
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getSongList() 
        {
            function = "SONGS";
            done = false; 
            if (ret == null)
                ret = new ArrayList<String>();
            else
                ret.clear();
            lastLoaderId = LOADER_ID1;
            LoaderManager lm = act.getSupportLoaderManager(); 
            Loader<Cursor> loader1 = lm.getLoader(LOADER_ID1);
            if (loader1 != null && loader1.isReset())
                loader1 = lm.restartLoader(LOADER_ID1, null, this);
            else
            {
                loader1 = lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID1, null, this);    
            }

            while(!done)
            {
                waitabit();
            }

            return ret; 
        }

        public static void editSelectedSongTitle(String newtitle) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }



        public static void setContinuePlayMode(PlayMode pm_) 
        {
            pm = pm_;       
        }

        public List<String> getPlayListNames() 
        {
            function = "PLAYLISTS";
            done = false; 
            if (ret == null)
                ret = new ArrayList<String>();
            else
                ret.clear();
            lastLoaderId = LOADER_ID2;
            LoaderManager lm = act.getSupportLoaderManager(); 
            lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID2, null,  this);

            while(!done)
            {
                waitabit();
            }

            function = "SONGS";

            return ret;

        }





        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) 
        {
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;

            switch (id) 
            {
            case LOADER_ID1:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(act, sourceUri, projections, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE); 
                break;
            case LOADER_ID2:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(act, uriPlaylists, projectionsPlaylist, null, null,  MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            cursorLoader.forceLoad();
            return cursorLoader;

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor data) 
        {
            cursor = data;
            loadArray(cursor);
            done = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) 
        {

            act.getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(lastLoaderId, null,  ( android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) 
        {
            onLoadFinished( loader, data);

        }




    }
```

I have tried to separate the database query from the usual nukes and crannies of my activity, long story short I have a button that if one clicks, getSongList is called, 
 I also have setActivity to turn the act member into the calling Activity,

I have read *ALL* relevant StackOverflow articles and everything on android development site. Some of you might object that I have to call some of my functions on the UI thread, I have done that too, to no avail. I have implemented the same set of code, in my main Activity, but still no matter what I do. OnLoadFinished is never called.

Comment: are you sure that your initLoader was called? please follow and see the code writing https://github.com/emil10001/AndroidSerialSQL/tree/sample and https://github.com/emil10001/AndroidSerialSQL

Comment: I am stepping through my code and after stepping over initLoader I can see that onCreateLoader is called, I also attached source, and did step into, which again confirmed that initLoader is called. thank you for your comment though, I appreciate it very much, and I am going to go read the stuff at those links, you provided right away.

Comment: yes sue..hope you will be able to solve this with the help of those links and code writing styles

Comment: this seems slightly weird:
loader1 = lm.restartLoader(LOADER_ID1, null, this) VS
loader1 = lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID1, null, act) ... does that mean your MediaInterface AND activity both have the callbacks implemented and you do intentionally call different ones ? Or if not... where do you want them implemented ? in your activity or in the MediaInterface ?

Comment: well, you see, Su-Au, in my desperation I have tried every thing, yes, you are right, I have had both MediaStoreInterface and Activity implement the callbacks, on the off chance that it is refusing to call OnLoadFinished on the account of some function not being called off of the UI thread. but it was no use. in both cases though initLoader is called from MediaStoreInterface which may or may not be off the UI thread, I am not sure, really there.

Comment: The main idea of using a loader is that you won't have to worry about threading and other things, no matter what the result will be presented in onLoadFinished on the main thread. if you could post some more code from activity + MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo, that would be helpful. Also you shouldn't call forceLoad(), since your CursorLoader isn't even started yet at that point.

Comment: I will modify my question to include all of my MediaStoreInterfaceFrodo, and the relevant part of my Activity code    but you are right, I shouldn't have to worry about which thread I am on.

Comment: I didn't find any relevant part, except that I have copied the same three overridden functions onCreateLoader, onLoadFinisihed, and onLoaderReset for the activity too. as you see, I do use forceLoad. nothing happens, after modifying the code many many times, I have never been able to see onLoadFinished called under any circumstances.

Comment: i meant, you shouldn't call forceLoad(), just return the loader. ForceLoader is only necessary if the Loader has been already started before and is not finished yet. I'm not sure that this will solve the problem, but i suggest removing it.

Comment: thanks again, I have done that too, to no avail, with forceload without forceload, it never finishes, if you have any working code, I would appreciate it a great deal if I can learn from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure what is causing the problem, as your code is incomplete, however your imports imply you might not use the activity from the support package:

> import android.app.Activity;

should be

> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

i actually don't see how your code could even compile, as the non-support-activity doesn't have a method called getSupportLoaderManager()

without knowing what the actual problem is, i'll post a sample i just created, i boiled down the code to what is actually necessary. Note however that you don't have to implement the LoaderCallback in an activity. This code is working, as i tested it.

```
package com.suhw.samples.mediastore;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;

public class QueryMediaStoreActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private final static String TAG = "QueryMediaStoreActivity";
    private static final int LOADER_ID1 = 1;
    private static final String[] audioMediaProjection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    private static final Uri audioMediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID1, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (id) {
            case LOADER_ID1:
                return new CursorLoader(this, audioMediaUri, audioMediaProjection, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        switch (cursorLoader.getId()) {
            case LOADER_ID1:
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished called:\n\tcursorCount:" + cursor.getCount());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so so much. so you can only call getSupportLoaderManager from a FragmentActivity?  My main activity was extended from an ActionBarActivity which itself is an extension of FragmentActivity, but I was not called getSupportLoaderManager in the UI thread of the FragmentActivity, I had set this in the MediaStoreInterface, which had a member Activity called act, like this
   MainActivity act; 

, and I would put an instance of my ActionBarActivity there as then when I wanted a list of say songs, I would called getSupportLoaderManager from there, with act.getSupportLoaderManager

Comment: Yes, getSupportLoaderManager() can only be called from FragmentActivity. In a non-support-library Activity you would simply call getLoaderManager().

Answer (score 1):

Change your **OncreateLoader**(), If dealing with multiple Loader then better use `switch()` statement.

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) 
    {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;

        switch (id) {
        case LOADER_ID1:
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), sourceUri, projections, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE); 
            break;
        case LOADER_ID2:
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uriPlaylists, projectionsPlaylist, null, null,  MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        cursorLoader.forceLoad();
        return cursorLoader;

    }
```

Edit:-

Use `getActivity()` instead of `act` for details [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)

**Note:-**
*The method getLoaderManager() is only available in the Fragment class. To get a LoaderManager in a FragmentActivity, call getSupportLoaderManager().*

Try like this.

Comment: thanks Amit, I have done that too, in a previous version I used that, the second type playlist, I would probably never use, but you see that's not the problem, the problem is that after doing every thing by the book, it loading is never finished, and onLoadFinished is never called.

Comment: as you can see above, my MediaStoreInterface is not an extention of an Activity or Fragment or FragmentActivity, may be it should be, but it's not. I am using getSupportLoaderManager, somewhere above, I have something like 
    setActivity(Activity act_)
    {
      act = act_
    }

  and that's how the MediaStoreInterface knows who the called activity and the parent context is, 

   you think that's the problem?

   I was trying to separate the logic of query and cursor and all that stuff from the UI and activity stuff, but sometimes android UI thread specs, makes it difficult to do that.

Comment: I now, understand what you are saying. I can only get a valid LoaderManager if I call getSupportLoaderManager on the UI thread of a FragmentActivity say in its onCreate method. right?